# Python- One if statement makes grid all "X" instead of just the side

Tags: python

I've made a code that prints a 10x10 grid of O's. I wanted to make all the sides show "X" instead, so I used some if statements. The first 2 works fine but the third one makes everything in the grid "X" and I don't know why.

```
size = 10

def main():
   setupBoard(size)
   printBoard()

def setupBoard(size):
   global board
   board = [[0] * size for _ in range(size)]
   for row in range(len(board)):
       for col in range(len(board)):
           if board[row][col] == board[0][col]: #top
               board[row][col] = "X"
           if board[row][col] == board[row][0]: #left
               board[row][col] = "X"
           if board[row][col] == board[size-1][size-1]: #right
               board[row][col] = "X"
           else:
               board[row][col] = "O"

def printBoard():
   for row in range(len(board)):
       print("")
       for col in range(len(board)):
           print(board[row][col], end = "  ")

main()
```

This outputs:

O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O
O  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X
O  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X
O  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X
O  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X
O  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X
O  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X
O  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X
O  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X
O  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X

When I want it to output:

X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X
X  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  X
X  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  X
X  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  X
X  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  X
X  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  X
X  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  X
X  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  X
X  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  X
X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X

I have no idea of what's wrong and I've been fooling around for some time trying to figure out what's wrong. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: From a brief glance, I'd give 50/50 odds that the problem is that your sequence of separate `if` statements should be a sequence of `elif`s, so the `else` doesn't end up overriding the work of one of the earlier clauses.\

Comment: Nope, that's not causing your bug—although it probably still is a bug, and I wouldn't be surprised if it bites you after fixing this one.

Comment: @abarnert Now everything is X's

Comment: Why are you comparing the cell contents rather than just `if row == 0`, `if col == size - 1`, etc.?

Comment: @glibdud Tried that now, and it works. Thanks for the help

Comment: `board = [[0] * size for _ in range(size)]` creates a list of references to the same list, not a list of independent lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is these tests:

```
if board[row][col] == board[0][col]: #top
```

This isn't actually testing that your current `row, col` are on the top row. It's testing that whatever value is in your current `row, col` (which will be `0`) is the same as whatever value is in the top of that column (which will be `X` or `O`.

You just want to do this:

```
if (row, col) == (0, col):
```

Or, more simply:

```
if row == 0:
```

---

The next problem is that you've tried to put the bottom and right together into a single test. But that means you're only going to put an `X` in the bottom right corner, not in every bottom and every right slot. You either need two `if` statements, or an `if` statement with an `or` in it.

---

Finally, you have a bunch of separate `if` statements. This means the `else` attaches to the last one of them, not to all of them. In other words, everything that isn't on the right, you'll set to `O`, which will overwrite the `X` you set for the top and left edges. To fix that, you need to use `elif` to chain the `if`s together.

---

Putting it all together:

```
if row == 0: # top
    board[row][col] = "X"
elif col == 0: # left
    board[row][col] = "X"
elif row == size-1: # bottom
    board[row][col] = "X"
elif col == size-1: # right
    board[row][col] = "X"
else:
    board[row][col] = "O"
```

Or you could `or` all those conditions together, because you do the same thing for every condition:

```
if row == 0 or col == 0 or row == size-1 or col == size-1:
    board[row][col] = "X"
else:
    board[row][col] = "O"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should not be the answer as it doesn't answer your question specifically -- but just do give you another perspective, you can make your life easier by doing it in such a way that you don't have to use an if statement at all, and gets rid of two levels of nesting. Usually in Python there is a better way than for/nexting through each item.

```
size = 10


def main():
    board = setup_board(size)
    print_board(board)


def setup_board(size):
    board = [[0] * size for _ in range(size)]
    board[0] = ['X'] * size
    board[-1] = ['X'] * size
    for i in range(1, size - 1):
        row = ['O'] * size
        row[0] = 'X'
        row[-1] = 'X'
        board[i] = row
    return board


def print_board(board):
    for row in range(len(board)):
        print("")
        for col in range(len(board)):
            print(board[row][col], end="  ")


main()
```